# Cannot access parameters in Iron because the trait bound plugin::Plugin<iron::Request> is not satisfied

Tags: rust, iron

I am exploring the capabilities of the Iron web framework. As far as I have figured out, the Iron core doesn't have an API to handle 
HTTP parameters so I tried to use the params crate.

```
error: the trait bound `params::Params: plugin::Plugin<iron::Request<'_, '_>>` is not satisfied [E0277]
    let map = req.get_ref::<Params>().unwrap();
                  ^~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
```

I haven't found trace of this bug and don't have a clue how to fix it.

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate params;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;
use params::*; //{self, Params, Value};

fn handle_user(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    use params::{Params, Value};

    let map = req.get_ref::<Params>().unwrap();

    match map.find(&["user", "name"]) {
        Some(&Value::String(ref name)) if name == "Marie" => {
            Ok(Response::with((iron::status::Ok, "Welcome back, Marie!")))
        },
        _ => Ok(Response::with(iron::status::NotFound)),
    }
}

fn main() {   
    Iron::new(handle_user).http("localhost:2330").unwrap();
}
```

Versions of libraries

```
iron = "0.4.0"
params = "0.2.2"
```

Comment: This is a [known issue in Iron and Params](https://github.com/iron/params/issues/23).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `params 0.2.2` crate [depends on](https://crates.io/crates/params) `iron ^0.3`, so you need to change the iron dependency version to `0.3`.

When using such a plugin crate, you have to make sure that versions match exactly. Sometimes a `cargo update` may be needed also.

---

In Rust, the same structs or traits taken from multiple versions of the same crate are treated as totally different. It usually results in an error like "`Pixel` expected, but found `Pixel`", or missing trait implementations as in your case.